# Fortran logical statement of loop index in multi-layer loops

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm debugging a Fortran project where something goofy went on for logical statement of loop index. Thanks to the comment of @Ross, the current code with problem is:

```
integer:: nz=5,na=10,nb=10,nk=10,nxi=10 
real(8),dimension(nz,na*nb*nk*nxi):: pi_ub 
integer:: i,j,k
real(8), dimension(nz,na*nb*nk*nxi,na*nb*nk):: nnpc,nndiv,obj_func

do i=1,nz
   do j=1,na*nb*nk*nxi 
    pi_ub(i,j)=some value
       do k=1,na*nb*nk
          nnpc(i,j,k)=some value
          nndiv(i,j,k)=some value
       end do 
   end do 
end do 

obj_func=0.0d0 

do i=1,nz
   do k=1,na*nb*nk
      do j=1,na*nb*nk*nxi 
        !Want to show the value of pi_ub(5,910) when k=1 
          if (i==5 .and. j==910 .and. k==1) then 
               print *, "pi_ub(5,910)", pi_ub(5,910) 
          end if

         !-----------------------------------------------------------
          if (nnpc(i,j,k)<0.0d0 .or. nndiv(i,j,k)<0.0d0) then 
               exit 
          else if (nnpc(i,j,k) >=0.0d0 .and. nndiv(i,j,k)>0.0d0) 
               obj_func=some value
          end if
         !------------------------------------------------------------
      end do 
   end do 
end do
```

The pi_ub(5,910) can be properly printed without if-endif sentence in the two dashed lines. But if there's such an if sentence, nothing is printed. It seems that the "exit" command is messing things up. But shouldn't code before "exit" run anyway? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked for me when testing. How are you compiling and running? Is this the complete code?

Comment: Thanks for your following up, @Ross! There is a IF sentence in the original code, which may seem to be the problem. I'll revise the question. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you were trying to do, but I'm glad you solved your problem.
It's possible you're confusing `exit` and `cycle` - you should look at both.

Comment: Yes. `exit` should be replaced by `cycle` in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up: OK, my understanding of "exit" is wrong. The code exits loops before "i==5 .and. j==910 .and. k==1" evoked, and the print command executed. So it all makes sense